# How to connect named pipe c# server to that of named pipe php client

Tags: c#, php, named-pipes

For the `php`, i used,

```
<?php
$pipe = popen("water-Pipe",'r+');
$read = fread($pipe,10);
echo $read;
pclose($pipe);
?>
```

It does not connect. In the c#, same file descriptor is used in `NamedPipeServerStream`. Any help?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I was testing for connection between named pipe server in c# with that of named pipe client. In the server,   i used                        `NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("water-pipe")` and for php client i used the above code. when i print var $pipe , it displays resourec id #4, but i does not read anything. I guess, my way is somewhere wrong. I am new to php, so thats why not very confident. And i am executing php code in the cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx)?

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/daf37585-fcdb-4a6e-8d7b-5f990c1c49bd/how-to-consume-wcf-service-from-php-client-?forum=wcf) is a question on how to connect a C# project with PHP

Windows Communication Foundation is a very handy tool for communication between programs and services, even written in different program languages.
You don't need to make the complex connections. This will be made for you.